# Обрезать часть строки js

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка такого типа "Дом на Вельяминовской (г. Москва, (м. Семеновская) ул. Вельяминовская, 27)"
Можно ли как-то с помощью js убрать ту часть что в круглых скобках что бы осталось значение "Дом на Вельяминовской" ? В регулярных выражениях не силен.

Comment: [/.+?(?=\h\()/](https://regex101.com/r/n7QanW/1)

Comment: @Эдуард, `\h` в js не поддерживается.

Comment: @Qwertiy♦ да, поэтому я в ответе его и не использовал.

Answer (score 1):

Если необходимо удалить все вложенные круглые скобки, можно использовать `.replace(/\([^()]*\)/g, '')` до тех пор, пока не останется совпадений.

Выражение `\([^()]*\)` находит символ `(`, затем ноль и более символов, отличных от `(` и `)` (`[^()]*`), а затем символ `)`.

Код на JavaScript:

```js
var s = "Дом на Вельяминовской (г. Москва, (м. Семеновская) ул. Вельяминовская, 27)";
var pat = /\([^()]*\)/;
while (pat.test(s)) {       // Пока есть совпадние (пока есть в строке (...))
   s = s.replace(pat, '');  // Удали его
}
console.log(s);
```

Comment: а такой вариант `/\([^(]*?\)/` не лучше для поиска?

Comment: @Grundy Не лучше.

Comment: а можно где-то сравнение посмотреть? Как работает один и как второй?

Comment: @Grundy https://regex101.com/r/r7Ov3P/1/debugger - https://regex101.com/r/r7Ov3P/2/debugger

Comment: что-то не понял почему точки считаются за один шаг, он же так же должен каждую проверить и сравнить с закрывающейся скобкой?

Comment: @Grundy Cмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41269355/3832970), как работают ленивые квантификаторы.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = 'Дом на Вельяминовской (г. Москва, (м. Семеновская) ул. Вельяминовская, 27)';
var patt = /(.+?)\s?\(.*/g;
str = str.replace(patt, '$1');
    
alert( str );
```